# Alternative to ForEach?

Tags: java, foreach, while-loop, cycle

I have the class Exam with the following attributes:

```
package logic;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exam {

    private int number;
    private Professor professor;
    private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();

    ... // getters, setters, etcetera

}
```

My question is about the constructor:

```
public Exam(Professor professor, ArrayList<Question> questions) {

    this.professor = professor;

    for(Question question : questions) // <---
        this.questions.add(question); // <---

}
```

Is there any alternative to foreach in order to add the questions? For example, using a while or another cycle? How could it be? I've been trying but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I tried using a while and an Iterator, but it was getting kinda messy...

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple [`List#addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)?

```
this.questions.addAll(questions);
```

---

Note, it would help if you explained *why* your current code is not working for you, and *how* it fails (compile error? runtime exception? something else?).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out... Actually the code was working correctly, but I had to find another way to do it as a request for an excercise.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

   this.questions = new ArrayList(questions);
2. [List#addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

   this.questions.addAll(questions);
3. Assignment

   this.questions = questions;

Answer (score 1):

```
// assign the passed ArrayList to the class attribute
this.questions = questions;
```